# Session doesn't exist joomla

Tags: joomla

I ve been sitting for 3 days with this problem. Still cant solve. 
I have copied my project and its database to wamp server.
Error is this:
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table
 'dbt.n0n8z_session' doesn't exist SQL=DELETE FROM `n0n8z_session`
 WHERE `time` < '1456571951'
I ve surfed internet, my configuration.php file is correct.
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: in phpmyadmin, only some tables displayed. But in mysql/data folder all tables exist

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 causes of this problem:

- The session table is corrupt
- The session table has been completely removed (possibly because of a hack)

Go to phpMyAdmin, and then select your Joomla database, and then repair the session table by running the following query:

```
REPAIR TABLE `n0n8z_session`
```

If you get a message along the "Table doesn't exist", then the table has been deleted. You should recreate it by running the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `n0n8z_session` (
  `session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `guest` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
  `time` varchar(14) DEFAULT '',
  `data` mediumtext,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It writes: Table 'test4.n0n8z_session' doesn't exist

Comment: but when i type SHOW TABLES, there is that table

Comment: and impossible to create that table too

Answer (score 1):

if you have a backup you only need create a new and clean data base, import the backup an change db user, name and password in configuration.php file.

I do not know if it works by importing the current database to a new one.